# Test unit pm2 module

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, module, pm2

I'm tring to write the test unit of a pm2-module with jest.

I wrote a module following [this](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/advanced/pm2-module-system/) guide but.. how can test it if there aren't any `module.exports` on the apps?

Of course I have try to write a test and this code:

```
'use strict';

const pm2Module = require('../app');

describe('Module PM2 env test', () => {
  test('First test', () => {
    console.log(pm2Module);
  });
});
```

Print an empty json: `{}`

Is it correct to add a `module.exports = pm2EnvModule;` on my module?
But then I have to mock `const pm2 = require('pm2');` right?

[here the implementation](https://github.com/Eomm/pm2-env-module/blob/master/app.js)

```
const pm2EnvModule = (config) => {
  pm2.list((err, processList) => {
    if (err) {
      log.error(err, 'Error on listing pm2 process');
      return;
    }

    processList
      .filter(process => process.name !== 'pm2-env-module')
      .forEach((process) => {
        log.debug('Check .env on process: %s', process.name);
        // do something to test
      });
  });
};

pmx.initModule({}, (err, conf) => {
  if (err) {
    pino.fatal(err, 'Error on init module');
    process.exit(2);
  }
  pm2EnvModule(conf);
});
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The link to the implementation returns a 404 for me, it might be better to put the relevant part of it inline in the question :) https://github.com/Eomm/pm2-env-module/blob/feature/logger/app.js

Comment: fixed, sorry for the link

Answer (score 0):

The examples don't have a `module.exports` because they are just being called not required. To test it you need to require it so a `module.exports` is required.

Comment: And what about the `pm2.list` function? I also think so that it must be exported the `pm2EnvModule` function